# HTML - XML data islands

Tags: html, xml

I am designing a web app and I intent to embed data on an XML island so that I can dynamically render it on an HTML table on the client-side based on options the users will select.

I have the broad concepts, but I need pointers on how to use DOM in navigating my XML. And how to update my XML island possibly for posting back to the server?

NB: I understand most of the dynamic HTML concepts and server and client side stuff, so feel free to be technical in your response.

Comment: @ykaganovich - Ok, all my users are in IE and its an intranet application. My existing model suits xml data island as per my analysis...

Comment: Nothing you said in the above description indicates that XML is preferable to JSON. If you have other information, it would be useful. Mostly, if your backand currently requires or produces specific XML, that would be a good argument. Otherwise, most languages have good support for JSON.

Comment: IE10 will drop support for them, so it may be worthwhile looking at an article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) from Mozilla, explaining how to use them with Firefox (and, by extension, other browsers I suppose) using HTML5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *W3C* HTML there are no XML data islands (unless you're referring to external XML file linked via frames loaded using Javascript), but you can re-use HTML elements and insert metadata in `class`, `title` (if you care about HTML4 validity), `data-*` (HTML5) or your custom attributes.

For DOM navigation you've got [DOM Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), like `element.childNodes`, `.nextSibling`, `.getAttribute()`, etc.

DOM can be verbose and tedious to use (e.g. when looking for elements in DOM you have to be careful to skip text nodes), so there are JS libraries like jQuery and Prototype built on top of it that offer more convenient API.

If you intend to a lot of DOM transformations, then Javascript API for [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) and [XSLT processor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) will be handy.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be done with XML.

However, I think it would be much easier if you used JSON instead of XML. That way, you can directly work with a Javascript object, which is friendlier than navigating XML DOM. Then you can send the serialized JSON form to the server using the [JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Patterns has some good examples for using data islands: http://ajaxpatterns.org/wiki/index.php?title=XML_Data_Island