# How to hide XML within HTML page in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an HTML page within which i need to store some xml. Below is the format

```
<HTML>

<XML>
<tag1>Val1</tag1>
<tag2>Val2</tag2>
</XML>

<script type= "javascript">
</script>

</HTML>
```

When I view this in IE, the xml is not displayed(node values) while the same is appearing in Firefox.

Any ideas on how to make it disappear in both browsers ?

Comment: Why do you need to store the XML within the HTML page?  Is it used by JavaScript or some external file that reads the HTML page or what?

Comment: `an HTML page within which i need to store some xml` need is such a strong word. Is there a requirement that can be implemented without storing XML in HTML. It shouldn't be done.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300210/html-xml-data-islands

Comment: @trott,@StuperUser : well we have multiple matrices and need to pick up values from one or more of them based on what the user selects, hence we came up with the XML data Island idea. This calculation needs to be done on a third party app which supports only HTML/Javascript. Any alternate solutions are more than welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
XML{
    display:none;
}
```

Storing XML within HTML does not sound like a good idea, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to store XML within an HTML page.

If you need to get some XML data to perform some operations on, use an Ajax request to get it. If you use jQuery, this would be just a few lines of code.

Comment: It used to be encouraged by Microsoft -- old versions of IE supported "XML Data Islands" within HTML pages. However, they were never part of any agreed standard. Some useful tips for alternatives may be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I also would suggest avoiding putting XML within an HTML page. But I see what you are trying to do. Let me suggest an alternative. In-page JSON data. I have been writing data from our database recently directly to the page as JSON data so I can transform it later with JQuery and libraries like Angular.js. Here is an example of storing a result set in JSON. This example was written using Idocs script but ASP, PHP, JSP could easily loop across a result set and generate the following JSON data. JQuery has built in filtering and sorting that you can use to transform the data or write your own in JavaScript.

```
//cached page data written as array of JSON objects
var rows = [];

//data written from UCM idocs
r = {"dDocType":"510k","dDescription":"510k Summaries","dGif":"archiv.gif","Display.default":"510k Summaries"};
rows[0] = r;
r = {"dDocType":"abstract","dDescription":"Abstracts and Posters","dGif":"archiv.gif","Display.default":"Abstracts and Posters"};
rows[1] = r;
r = {"dDocType":"addendum","dDescription":"Addendum","dGif":"document.gif","Display.default":"Addendum"};
rows[2] = r;
r = {"dDocType":"advertising","dDescription":"Advertising","dGif":"archiv.gif","Display.default":"Advertising"};
rows[3] = r;
r = {"dDocType":"advertising","dDescription":"Funky Advertising","dGif":"archiv.gif","Display.default":"Advertising"};
rows[4] = r;
```